# How do I make the condition of a while loop, as long as all the values of a given vector are equal?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and am trying to make a function which with each "generation" replicates one individual of a population and terminates another. Here is what I have done so far,

```
simulate_moran<-function(n){
  population <- c(rep(0, (n - 1)), 1)
  ind_die<-(sample(1:n,size=1))
  ind_repr<-(sample(1:n,size=1))
  while(sum(population)>=1 & sum(population)<=4){
    population[ind_die]<-population[ind_repr]
  }
  return(population)
}
simulate_moran(5)
```

How can I set the condition for the while loop so that it loops until there is only one type (0 or 1) of an individual.
If you choose to help thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `all()` method in `base` (see `?base::all`), which you could use to check if all elements are equal to the first. Like

```r
while (!all(population == population[[1]])) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I substituted what you suggested into my code whoever when I try to simulate_moran( 5), r just loads and never actually produces anything. Do you know why?

Comment: @Charles-DavidBisson you need the sampling steps inside the loop, otherwise you just keep overwriting the same position every time.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. thank you very much for your help